# Can I say these curves are null-homotopic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My question is really simple. Can I say these curves in $\mathbb R^2$ are null-homotopic, since they are in a simply connected space? I'm asking that because I can't see intuitively the curves $B$ and $C$ continuously shrinking to the base point.

[image]

Comment: Yes, they are all nullhomotopic in $\Bbb R^2$ as $\Bbb R^2$ is simply connected and moreover even contractible. Just contract everything to one point by $(t,x) \to tx$ for $t\in [0,1]$ and $x$ any point on any of the curves.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be any point on your curve. Imagine a straight line between $x$ and the point you drew. Do this for all points. And then do the following: Imagine the curve moving along these lines to the point you drew. That is an example of a nullhomotopic mapping.

So of course, the answer is yes, for else the homotopy group of $\mathbb R^2$ would be nontrivial. But in order to prove that, one proves, of course, that all cycles are homotopic to the constant map, and the construction I tried to describe above is just the desired homotopy.

Comment: If, however, you would take a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ that has a hole, nothign could be guaranteed. If you place the hole in the midst of one of your constructions, very probably it would no longer be nullhomotopic in the new, proper subspace with the hole (but still in $\mathbb R^2$). The point is where the homotopy is defined.